# Java - avoid switch statements for static functions

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, switch-statement

Check out this code -

```
switch(kind) {
     case "green" :
           GreenKind.doSomething(); // Static function
     break;
     case "white" :
           WhiteKind.doSomething(); // Static function
     break;
     case "blue" :
           BlueKind.doSomething(); // Static function
     break;
     case "yellow" :
           YellowKind.doSomething(); // Static function
     break;
}
```

There is a way to avoid the switch statement? as it smells real bad.

Maybe to somethnig like this? -

```
kinds.get(kind).doSomething();
```

The problem with my solution is that the functions are static, and i can't implement an interface with static functions. If you didn't understood why i wrote interface its because i wanted to use polymorphism in my solution above.

Comment: Sounds like you should have an enum instead of those static methods...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would have an `enum` like so:

```
enum Kind {
    GREEN {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            GreenKind.doSomething();
        }
    },
    WHITE {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            WhiteKind.doSomething();
        }
    };

    public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

And pass around an enum constant, for example this method:

```
public static void invoke(Kind kind) {
    kind.doSomething();
}
```

and call it like:

```
invoke(Kind.GREEN);
```

This way looks cleaner, and moreover it's safer, as you can have only a fixed set of inputs.

Comment: That is a really classy refactor. Congrats !

Comment: +1: Omg. After 6 years of Java experience, I still didn't know that this was possible using enums... :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux it is even possible to pass both "instance variables" and methods into enums at the same time; syntax is a little on the heavy side, though

Comment: @fge I didn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an enum. Example for a single entry enum:

```
public enum Kind
{
    GREEN("green")
    {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() { /* do something */ }
    };

    private final String asString;

    public abstract void doSomething();

    Kind(final String asString)
    {
        this.asString = asString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return asString; }
}
```

In code, you would then do `Kind.valueOf(kind.toUppercase()).doSomething();`.

This would also allow you to get rid of {Green,Red}Kind with a little work: just put all the logic into the enum.

Comment: I liked both your and Rohit Jain's answers, will accept in a few moments. hard to choose :) Thank you all by the way